# Как для всех тегов input с заданным атрибутом выставить, например, атрибут checked=false?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Вставил теги input type="radio" со своим атрибутом data-group:

```
<input type="radio" id="id1" data-group="group1">
<input type="radio" id="id2" data-group="group1"><br>
<input type="radio" id="id3" data-group="group2">
<input type="radio" id="id4" data-group="group2"><br>
```

Как у всех элементов input type="radio", у которых data-group равен "group1", установить checked=false?

Comment: @Etki, как это нечего ухудшать? Да я бы на дуэль вызвал за это :)  
У него есть недостатки, порой очень критичные, но это как "Доктор Хаус" среди сериалов по медицине - вроде один из многих, но явно выделяется лидером по всем параметрам.  
jQuery предоставляет интерфейс `JS - программист`, но, как известно, интерфейсы не должны заменять нативный код.  
В недрах ядра происходят манипуляции, которые, с одной стороны, проводят неявно кроссбраузерность, с другой, лишают свободы действия ИМХО.

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
var group = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][data-group="group1"]');
[].forEach.call(group, function(e){
  el.checked = false;
});
```

Comment: Добавлю на jquery пример - http://jsfiddle.net/a472sfy2/

$('input:radio[data-group="group1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: @xfloooo, аааа, чувак, подключать jQuery для столь простой операции - грех, хуже которого найти сложно что-либо!  
Достали эти недокодеры, которые лезут с этой гадостью везде, нативного JS вообще не знают!  
Блин, бомбануло, извини :)

Comment: @TheDoctor былa тема недавно - `как сравнить строки с помощью jQuery`.

Comment: > аааа, чувак, подключать jQuery для столь простой операции - грех, хуже которого найти сложно что-либо!

чуваки, ну двадцать первый век, кончайте экономить на спичках.

копия из cdn практичеси гарантированно валяется у клиента в браузере

подключая одну библиотеку, вы практически гарантированно обезопасите себя от возможных браузер-депендент костылей и обеспечите легкое расширение

никогда ни один скрипт не будет целиком состоять из такого примера, а когда оно упрется в стену нерасширяемости, придется переписывать двести строк на jquery просто так, из личной гордости

Comment: @argamidon, да не говори - я долго не мог понять, что за адова хрень там творится.  
За это я и не люблю jQuery - из удобного полуфреймворка-полубиблиотеки она превратилась в ужасного монстра-библиотеку, которая из-за возможности одной строкой вызвать чудо, опустила планку вхождения в очень простой (на самый первый и поверхностный взгляд) язык JavaScript до самого низа.  
Один из лучших языков из-за кучи школоты, считающих, что знают JS в совершенстве потому, что подключили jQuery и нашли элемент, приобрёл печальную репутацию.

Comment: @Etki, дело не в том, чтобы отказываться от библиотеки - это дело каждого (я, например, собрал себе библиотечку с необходимыми именно мне инструментами и рад жизни), но дело в том, что доходит до того, что некоторые подключат jQuery для поиска одного элемента в скрипте.  
ОДНОГО, мать его, элемента!  
Вариант с кэшем может быть, но далеко не обязателен - юзер может быть с чистым кэшем или вообще запретить браузеру кэшировать (да, да, есть параноики), может кэш забит, может CDN упадёт (однажды лично застал это ночью), может нерентабельно подключать из-за пары строк кода, может...  
Ну понятно.

Comment: @TheDoctor, угу. И что в этом страшного?

Comment: @Etki, в том, что некоторые удивляются что jQuery - это не нативный JS?  
В том, что без jQuery многие из "программистов" даже элемент не способны найти?  
В том, что jQuery изменяет сам JS, причём не в лучшую сторону?  
В том, именно из-за него у JS плохая репутация и он обесценивается из-за наплыва тех, кто "знает" сабж, хотя, если честно, этот кто-то даже jQuery до конца не знает?  
В том, ...

Если надо, могу ещё добавить, но лень :)

Comment: @TheDoctor,

> что jQuery изменяет сам JS, при чём не в лучшую сторону?

Было б там что ухудшать, бггг

Драма на ровном месте. Меня, тебя можно точно так же поспрашивать про сортировки (которые совсем не rocket science) и вынести примерно такой же вердикт.

Comment: @TheDoctor, как-то расточительно создавать массив, только чтобы не писать 'Array.prototype'.

Comment: > в том, что некоторые удивляются что jQuery - это не нативный JS?

эммм.. в таком случае всё, что написано на js - не нативный js... 

(в том в смысле, что если ненативность должна напрягать)

Comment: я вначале сделал так: на jquery... но потом понадобилось обойти все элементы и самый первый ответ forEach.call очень пригодился!!! спасиб